# constructor instrument in class instrument cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, arrays, string, constructor, stringbuilder

I am currently trying to Design and implement a stringed musical instrument class.

The instructions for this assignment are:

1. Data fields for your instrument should include number of strings, an array of string names representing string names (e.g. E,A,D,G),
2. boolean fields to determine if the instrument is tuned, and if the instrument is currently playing. You are welcome to add additional data fields if you like.
3. A constructor method that set the tuned and currently playing fields to false.
4. Other methods 1) to tune the instrument,
5. to start the instrument playing, and  3) to stop the instrument from playing. 
   Other methods as you see fit (Add at least one unique method).

That is the main file, I then have to:

create a Java test class that simulates using your instrument class.  In your test class be you should at a minimum: a) Construct 10 instances of your instrument, 
b) tune your instruments, 
c) Start playing your instrument, 
d) Call your unique method, and 
e) Stop playing your instruments.
 (Hint: Arrays and Loops will make your job easier and result in more efficient code!)

I have created both files but my main project file has some issues that prevent me from seeing an output when I test it. (I’m using netbeans to test the program if that helps at all.)

My current test file has no errors but I know that is necessary for the outputs to print on the main java file so I also attached that as well.

here is my main project java file:

```
import java.io.*;

/* File: KenMasonp3.java
* Author: Kenneth Mason
* Date: 19-04-2014
* Purpose: Design and implement a stringed musical instrument class 
* Code edited/modified by myself with sources from LEO classroom modules, Liang
* book, javaprogrammingforums.com, dreamincode.net, and the instructor
*/

public class KenMasonp3 { // start main class

// start main method

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 


    //creates a file named from the command line argument

    File outputFile = new File(args[0]);

    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outputFile);

    //creates an array of 10 objects

    instrument[] guitarArray = new instrument[10];

    /*calls methods to construct, tune, play, 
     *get the string names and stop the instrument array
     */

    instrument.constructGuitarArray(guitarArray, output);
    instrument.tuneGuitar(guitarArray, output);
    instrument.playGuitar(guitarArray, output);
    instrument.getStrings(guitarArray, output);
    instrument.stopGuitar(guitarArray, output);

    //close the file
    output.close();

} // main method end

 } // end main class


 // Guitar class

  class instrument {

//method to construct the instrument array

public static instrument[] constructGuitarArray(instrument[] array, 
        PrintWriter file) {


    //creates a random instrument

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {


    /******** CODE BELOW ALWAYS GIVES ME THIS ERROR EVEN WHEN I COPY PASTE ******
        error is: 
        * " constructor instrument in class instrument cannot be applied to given types;
            required: no arguments
            found: int
            reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length " 
        */


        array[i] = new instrument((int) (1 + Math.random() * 12));







        //prints the creation message to file



        /******** CODE BELOW ALWAYS GIVES ME THIS ERROR EVEN WHEN I COPY PASTE ******
        * error is: cannot find symbol variable createdMessage 
        * location: class instrument
        */
        file.println(array[i].createdMessage);
    }

    //returns array to main method

    return array;
}

//method that calls the tune method for the instrument array

public static void tuneGuitar(instrument[] array, 
    PrintWriter file) {


    //tunes all objects in the array

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {




         /******** CODE BELOW ALWAYS GIVES ME THIS ERROR EVEN WHEN I COPY PASTE ******
         * error is: cannot find symbol method 
         * location: class instrument
         */

        array[i].setTune(true);




        //prints the tuned message to file




         /******** CODE BELOW ALWAYS GIVES ME THIS ERROR EVEN WHEN I COPY PASTE ******
         *error is: cannot find symbol variable tunedMessage
         * location: class instrument
         */

        file.println(array[i].tunedMessage);
    }
}

//method that calls the play method for the instrument array

public static void playGuitar(instrument[] array, PrintWriter file) {

    //plays all objects in the array

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        /******** CODE BELOW ALWAYS GIVES ME THIS ERROR EVEN WHEN I COPY PASTE ******
         * error is: cannot find symbol method setPlay(boolean)
         * location: class instrument
         */

        array[i].setPlay(true);

        //prints the tuned message to file

         /******** CODE BELOW ALWAYS GIVES ME THIS ERROR EVEN WHEN I COPY PASTE ******
         * error is: cannot find symbol variable playMessage 
         * location: class instrument
         */
        file.println(array[i].playMessage);
    }
}

//method that calls the getStrings method for the instrument array

public static void getStrings(instrument[] array, PrintWriter file) {


    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        /******** CODE BELOW ALWAYS GIVES ME THIS ERROR EVEN WHEN I COPY PASTE ******
         * error is: cannot find symbol method setString(boolean)
         * location: class instrument
         */
        array[i].setString(true);

        //prints the tuned message to file

        /******** CODE BELOW ALWAYS GIVES ME THIS ERROR EVEN WHEN I COPY PASTE ******
         * error is: cannot find symbol variable stringMessage 
         * location: class instrument
         */

        file.println(array[i].stringMessage);
    }
}

//method that calls the stopGuitar method for the instrument array

public static void stopGuitar(instrument[] array, PrintWriter file) {

     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {


         /******** CODE BELOW ALWAYS GIVES ME THIS ERROR EVEN WHEN I COPY PASTE ******
         * error is: cannot find symbol method setStop(boolean)
         * location: class instrument
         */

         array[i].setStop(true);

        //prints the tuned message to file

        /******** CODE BELOW ALWAYS GIVES ME THIS ERROR EVEN WHEN I COPY PASTE ******
         * error is: cannot find symbol variable stopMessage
         * location: class instrument
         */
        file.println(array[i].stopMessage);
    }
}
```

Note:  file outputFile = new File(args[0]);

because I need to write the output from your Instrument class methods to a text file that a user entered from the command line arguments

If you can see, my main problem seems to be this line of code:

```
array[i] = new instrument((int) (1 + Math.random() * 12));
```

The error says in netbeans: 
" constructor instrument in class instrument cannot be applied to given types;
        required: no arguments 
        found: int 
        reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length "

I think it's because of this error that I'm getting cannot find symbol on many of my other parts of code.

If anyone needs my text file it is here (but has no apparent errors):

```
/* File: KenMasonp3.java
* Author: Kenneth Mason
* Date: 19-04-2014
* Purpose: Design and implement a stringed musical instrument class 
* Code edited/modified by myself with sources from LEO classroom modules, Liang
* book, javaprogrammingforums.com, dreamincode.net
*/
public class KenMasonp3test { // start main class

    public static void main(String[] args) {

}
//instrument class

class guitarInstrument { 


//private variable declarations
private boolean tuned, playing;

private String guitarType;

private String[] stringNames;

//public variable declarations

public String playMessage, tunedMessage, createdMessage;

public StringBuilder guitarStringsNames;

//default constructor that generates a random 6 string instrument

public guitarInstrument() {

    int strings = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 12);

    //generates array based on number of strings

    String[] stringNames = new String[strings];

    //fills string array with random string names

    for (int i = 0; i < stringNames.length; i++) {
        stringNames[i] = String.valueOf((char)('A' + Math.random() * 
                ('G' - 'A' + 1)));
    }

    this.stringNames = stringNames;

    //sets instrument name

    guitarType = "random " + strings + "-string instrument";

    //sets tuned and playing to false

    tuned = false;
    playing = false;

    //sets string for construction of the instrument

    createdMessage = "You created a " + guitarType;

} // end of guitar() method

//constructor allowing specific amount of strings

public guitarInstrument(int strings) {
    //creates specific instrument based on number of strings input

    if (strings == 6) {

        //creates and fills string array

        String[] stringNames = {"E", "A", "D", "G", "B", "E"};
        this.stringNames = stringNames;

        //names instrument

        guitarType = "guitar";

   } // end if

    else {
        //creates and fills string array

        String[] stringNames = new String[strings];

        //fills array with random string names

        for (int i = 0; i < stringNames.length; i++) {
            stringNames[i] = String.valueOf((char)('A' + Math.random() 
                    * ('G' - 'A' + 1)));
        }
        this.stringNames = stringNames;

        //names instrument

        guitarType = strings + "-string instrument";

    } // end else

    //sets tuned and playing to false

    tuned = false;
    playing = false;

    //sets string for construction of the instrument

    createdMessage = "You created a " + guitarType;

    } // end guitar (in strings) method

    //method to tune or untune the instrument

    public void setTune(boolean tune) {
    this.tuned = tune;

    //sets string for tuned instrument
    if (tuned == true) {
        tunedMessage = "The " + guitarType + " is now in tune";
         } // end tuned if

    //sets string for untuned instrument

    else {
        tunedMessage = "The " + guitarType + " is out of tune";

        } // end of tuned else

     } // end of setTune method

     //method to play or stop the instrument

     public void playGuitarInstrument(boolean play) {
    this.playing = true; 

    // sets string for playing instrument

    if (playing == true) {
        playMessage = "The" + guitarType + "is now playing";

    } // end playing if

    // sets string for unplayed instrument

    else {
        playMessage = "The" + guitarType + "has stopped";

    } // end play else

    } // end of playGuitarInstrument method

    //method to display the string names of the instrument

    public void getStrings() {

    //sets stringbuilder with default intro statement

    StringBuilder guitarStringNames = new StringBuilder();

    System.out.println("The has the following strings:" 
            + guitarStringNames);


           } // end of getString method

       } // end of guitarInstrument method

    } // end of main class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 new instrument((int) (1 + Math.random() * 12));
```

This line has your problem. `instrument` does not have a constructor which takes an integer as a parameter.

Comment: Ok, I tried to add a constructor for instrument inside the main class using:

`Instrument instrument = new instrument();`

but it gives an error saying: "Instrument " - cannot find symbol"

I put the constructor in the main class and in the instrument class but I get the same error. I may be writing the constructor incorrectly I'll keep looking it up.

Comment: the class is named `instrument`, not `Instrument`. You should name it `Instrument`.

Comment: Ah ok.

edit: even changing the Instrument to instrument I still have the same error. I may be creating the constructor incorrectly.

Comment: You need to name your class `Instrument`

Comment: Even with naming my class `Instrument` and inputting the constructor

`Instrument instrument = new Instrument();` in the `Instrument` class I get the same error in the `array[i] = new instrument((int) (1 + Math.random() * 12));`